# Why could we only divide the displacement x into arbitrarily many subintervals instead of dividing the force F when calculating the work done?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function

The definition of **work done in moving the object from *a* to *b*** using integral is $$W=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \,dx$$
where the force *F* is a function of displacement *x*, namely $F=f(x)$

It is makes so much sense to me that the interval [*a*, *b*] is divided evenly into arbitrarily many subintervals $\Delta x$, and the work done during each subinterval is $f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x$, where $x_{i}^{*}$ is the **sample point**. Then add these subintervals of work done together and take the limit, we have the work done formula $$W=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \,dx$$

If the displacement *x* is a(n) (inverse) function of *F*, that is, $f^{-1}(F)=x$, then it is also very plausible that the work done is $$W=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(F) \,dF$$Because the force *F* is divided into arbitrarily many subintervals $\Delta F$, and the work done during each subinterval is $f^{-1}(F_{i}^{*})\Delta F$, where $F_{i}^{*}$ is **sample point**. By the similar idea and thought as above, I conclude that $$W=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f^{-1}(F_{i}^{*})\Delta F\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(F) \,dF$$

**However, the second work done formula $W=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(F) \,dF$ is wrong!** In terms of Methematics, we can see from the *F-x* graph that $$W=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \,dx=bf(b)-af(a)-\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(F) \,dF$$ This is the property of integral of any inverse function. But in terms of Physics, I think that I use the correct idea of integration to find work done. Because with respect to displacement *x*, the **upper limit** and the **lower limit** of the definite integral are *a* and *b*, respectively, which means that the object is at the point *x=a* in the beginning and at the point *x=b* in the end. With respect to to force *F*, the integral also makes sense to me, since the **upper limit** and the **lower limit** are *f(a)* and *f(b)*, respectively, which represents that in the beginning, the force is *F=f(a)* and in the end, the force is *F=f(b)*.

**My question is: what's wrong with my second 'fantastic' idea work done formula $W=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(F) \,dF$? Why could we only divide the displacement *x* into arbitrarily many subintervals instead of dividing the force *F*? Can anyone help me out? Thank you so much!**

Comment: I would expect that since $f^{-1}F=x$, your second integral is just integrating $x$, and not the actual forces involved, but I’m not sure

Comment: yes, at first I had a very similar with you, but it turned out to be complicated-I couldn't integrate the formula to get the expected answer. Bur now I have already got a valuable answer from another person. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382726/why-is-small-work-done-always-taken-as-dw-f-cdot-dx-and-not-dw-x-cdot-df